# How to add the custom time tag in wp contact form 7 plugin

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I use the cf7 plugin for creating the booking form . i need the time field in the form but i don't no known about how i do this because  there is no option for the the time on the tags .
please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and simplest way to get time as an input is to add it as a dropdown/Select.

Example :

Time
[select select-time "10:00 AM " "11:00 AM" "12:00 PM" "01:00 PM" "02:00 PM" "03:00 PM" "04:00 PM" "05:00 PM" "06:00 PM" "07:00 PM" "08:00 PM" "09:00 PM" "10:00 PM"]

Comment: Thank you! The simplicity of that is exactly what was necessary - no need to complicate things.

Answer (score 1):

**TL,DR;**

You can create your own custom tags.

The function used for it is [`wpcf7_add_form_tag()`](https://contactform7.com/2015/01/10/adding-a-custom-form-tag/).

**More in Length:**

Since the direct question is `how to add custom Time tag..`, I will answer in length,also for others needing custom tags. But if you just want a simple / Fast / Pre-made solution like a plugin you can look @neal-developer answer.

If you really talking about 'time' and not 'dateTime' or 'datePicker' than there is already a simple example of current time from the [CF7 help](https://contactform7.com/2015/01/10/adding-a-custom-form-tag/) that I linked above:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_add_form_tag_text' );

function wpcf7_add_form_tag_text() {
    wpcf7_add_form_tag(
        array( 'text', 'text*', 'email', 'email*', 'url', 'url*', 'tel', 'tel*' ),
        'wpcf7_text_form_tag_handler', array( 'name-attr' => true ) );
}

add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'custom_add_form_tag_clock' );
```

Then the callback :

```
function custom_add_form_tag_clock() {
    wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'clock', 'custom_clock_form_tag_handler' ); // "clock" is the type of the form-tag
}

function custom_clock_form_tag_handler( $tag ) {
    return date_i18n( get_option( 'time_format' ) );
}
```

which will allow you to use the custom tag :

```
Current Time: [clock]
```

and the result should be :

```
Current Time: 12:16 pm
```

At any rate, if you need another field ( like dateTime, datePicker etc - you can always use there custom tags to actually create anything you want .. )  But for simple Date there is always the [HTML5 field used in CF7](https://contactform7.com/date-field/) like :

```
[date* your-date min:2013-01-01 max:2013-12-31 step:7 class:required "2013-04-01"]
```

For any other type you can easily understand from the examples how to add custom tags, and fields..

**EDIT II**

If you want to save the field into database you will have to hook into CF7 using one of the possible hooks, for example `wpcf7_before_send_mail()` which allow you to get all the fields before the mail is sent ( search for it )

Comment: https://www.spacestore.co/bookings/

Hi thank for reply but i need to select time like in the mention URL please check 

with the code the clock tag is generated and time showing on fronted .....can i create whole functionality for select time in this tag ?

Comment: you can put whatever you want in the `custom_form_tag_handler`, including any input fields / select or whatever you want to be the output in the front end..

Comment: Hiii!!!!!!   i created the custum time field tag but i dont how i save this field data in the CF7 database table?????/Are you know?

Comment: Yes, you will need to hook somewhere, for example on `wpcf7_before_send_mail()`. please see my update. and if you have other difficulties regarding saving data from cf7 you should really accept this answer to mark it closed and open a new one..

Answer (score 0):

by default there is not any related field for the date and time picker.
You can use this plugin and after configuration you can add date and time picker in CF7:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/date-time-picker-field/

Comment: Date field ( without time ) is existing in HTML5 and [supported in CF7](https://contactform7.com/date-field/)

Comment: thanks for reply ...i already tried this but i have also need the time tag on time of mail but that time i didn't get the time so i think this one is not in my use .